# How to use both Firebase Authentication and Realtime Database

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Now I'm working on a REACT project which I want to use firebase. At first, I use Firebase Authentication and it work fine.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '----',
    authDomain: '----',
    projectId: '----',
    storageBucket: '----',
    messagingSenderId: '----',
    appId: '----',
    measurementId: '----',
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const auth = getAuth(app)

export auth
```

but when I add the `databaseURL` it shows an error

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '----',
    authDomain: '----',
    projectId: '----',
    databaseURL: '----',
    storageBucket: '----',
    messagingSenderId: '----',
    appId: '----',
    measurementId: '----',
}
```

```
error - FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app).
    at initializeApp (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/MUICT/Year%204/Sem%201/Practical%20Se/mutelu/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:433:33)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./firebase/config.js:35:72) {
  code: 'app/duplicate-app',
  customData: { appName: '[DEFAULT]' },
  page: '/searchAmulet'
}
```

So how can I fix this problem

I try to use `getApps()` but it didn't work plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single Firebase project, you should only run `initializeApp` exactly once in your code. If you need to have the database URL, make sure it is included right away when you call `initializeApp`.

If you need to access multiple Firebase projects from your app (this is relatively uncommon), you can do so by explicitly giving them a name. While there can be only `[DEFAULT]` project, there can be multiple named projects - as long as they all have unique names. For more on this, see the documentation on [configuring multiple project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects).

And finally, since this is about the Realtime Database, you can also leave the `databaseURL` out of the configuration entirely, and instead pass that URL to the API when you [get the database instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#getdatabase):

```
const db = getDatabase(getApp(), "your database URL");
```